# How to set latex path for matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, latex

I am trying to plot latex with matplotlib.
I've installed latex with pip.
this [example](https://matplotlib.org/users/mathtext.html#example) works well

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
t = np.arange(0.0, 2.0, 0.01)
s = np.sin(2*np.pi*t)

plt.plot(t,s)
plt.title(r'$\alpha_i > \beta_i$', fontsize=20)
plt.text(1, -0.6, r'$\sum_{i=0}^\infty x_i$', fontsize=20)
plt.text(0.6, 0.6, r'$\mathcal{A}\mathrm{sin}(2 \omega t)$',
         fontsize=20)
plt.xlabel('time (s)')
plt.ylabel('volts (mV)')
plt.show()
```

while `matplotlib.rcParams['text.usetex'] = True` encounters latex error.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.rcParams['text.usetex'] = True
t = np.arange(0.0, 2.0, 0.01)
s = np.sin(2*np.pi*t)

plt.plot(t,s)
plt.title(r'$\alpha_i > \beta_i$', fontsize=20)
plt.text(1, -0.6, r'$\sum_{i=0}^\infty x_i$', fontsize=20)
plt.text(0.6, 0.6, r'$\mathcal{A}\mathrm{sin}(2 \omega t)$',
         fontsize=20)
plt.xlabel('time (s)')
plt.ylabel('volts (mV)')
plt.show()
```

which produces this stack

> --------------------------------------------------------------------------- FileNotFoundError                         Traceback (most recent call
>   last)
>   ~/anaconda3/envs/tf11/lib/python3.6/site-packages/IPython/core/formatters.py
>   in **call**(self, obj)
>       330                 pass
>       331             else:
>   --> 332                 return printer(obj)
>       333             # Finally look for special method names
>       334             method = get_real_method(obj, self.print_method)
>
> ~/anaconda3/envs/tf11/lib/python3.6/site-packages/IPython/core/pylabtools.py
>   in (fig)
>       235 
>       236     if 'png' in formats:
>   --> 237         png_formatter.for_type(Figure, lambda fig: print_figure(fig, 'png', **kwargs))
>       238     if 'retina' in formats or 'png2x' in formats:
>       239         png_formatter.for_type(Figure, lambda fig: retina_figure(fig, **kwargs))
>
> ~/anaconda3/envs/tf11/lib/python3.6/site-packages/IPython/core/pylabtools.py
>   in print_figure(fig, fmt, bbox_inches, **kwargs)
>       119 
>       120     bytes_io = BytesIO()
>   --> 121     fig.canvas.print_figure(bytes_io, **kw)
>       122     data = bytes_io.getvalue()
>       123     if fmt == 'svg':
>
> ~/anaconda3/envs/tf11/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/backend_bases.py
>   in print_figure(self, filename, dpi, facecolor, edgecolor,
>   orientation, format, bbox_inches, **kwargs)    2047
>   orientation=orientation,    2048                         dryrun=True,
>   -> 2049                         **kwargs)    2050                     renderer = self.figure._cachedRenderer    2051
>   bbox_artists = kwargs.pop("bbox_extra_artists", None)
>
> ~/anaconda3/envs/tf11/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_agg.py
>   in print_png(self, filename_or_obj, *args, **kwargs)
>       508 
>       509         """
>   --> 510         FigureCanvasAgg.draw(self)
>       511         renderer = self.get_renderer()
>       512
>
> ~/anaconda3/envs/tf11/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_agg.py
>   in draw(self)
>       400         toolbar = self.toolbar
>       401         try:
>   --> 402             self.figure.draw(self.renderer)
>       403             # A GUI class may be need to update a window using this draw, so
>       404             # don't forget to call the superclass.
>
> ~/anaconda3/envs/tf11/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/artist.py
>   in draw_wrapper(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
>        48                 renderer.start_filter()
>        49 
>   ---> 50             return draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
>        51         finally:
>        52             if artist.get_agg_filter() is not None:
>
> ~/anaconda3/envs/tf11/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/figure.py
>   in draw(self, renderer)    1650     1651
>   mimage._draw_list_compositing_images(
>   -> 1652                 renderer, self, artists, self.suppressComposite)    1653     1654
>   renderer.close_group('figure')
>
> ~/anaconda3/envs/tf11/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/image.py
>   in _draw_list_compositing_images(renderer, parent, artists,
>   suppress_composite)
>       136     if not_composite or not has_images:
>       137         for a in artists:
>   --> 138             a.draw(renderer)
>       139     else:
>       140         # Composite any adjacent images together
>
> ~/anaconda3/envs/tf11/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/artist.py
>   in draw_wrapper(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
>        48                 renderer.start_filter()
>        49 
>   ---> 50             return draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
>        51         finally:
>        52             if artist.get_agg_filter() is not None:
>
> ~/anaconda3/envs/tf11/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/axes/_base.py
>   in draw(self, renderer, inframe)    2602
>   renderer.stop_rasterizing()    2603 
>   -> 2604         mimage._draw_list_compositing_images(renderer, self, artists)    2605     2606         renderer.close_group('axes')
>
> ~/anaconda3/envs/tf11/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/image.py
>   in _draw_list_compositing_images(renderer, parent, artists,
>   suppress_composite)
>       136     if not_composite or not has_images:
>       137         for a in artists:
>   --> 138             a.draw(renderer)
>       139     else:
>       140         # Composite any adjacent images together
>
> ~/anaconda3/envs/tf11/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/artist.py
>   in draw_wrapper(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
>        48                 renderer.start_filter()
>        49 
>   ---> 50             return draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
>        51         finally:
>        52             if artist.get_agg_filter() is not None:
>
> ~/anaconda3/envs/tf11/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/axis.py
>   in draw(self, renderer, *args, **kwargs)    1185         ticks_to_draw
>   = self._update_ticks(renderer)    1186         ticklabelBoxes, ticklabelBoxes2 = self._get_tick_bboxes(ticks_to_draw,
>   -> 1187                                                                 renderer)    1188     1189         for tick in ticks_to_draw:
>
> ~/anaconda3/envs/tf11/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/axis.py
>   in _get_tick_bboxes(self, ticks, renderer)    1123         for tick in
>   ticks:    1124             if tick.label1On and
>   tick.label1.get_visible():
>   -> 1125                 extent = tick.label1.get_window_extent(renderer)    1126
>   ticklabelBoxes.append(extent)    1127             if tick.label2On and
>   tick.label2.get_visible():
>
> ~/anaconda3/envs/tf11/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/text.py
>   in get_window_extent(self, renderer, dpi)
>       927             raise RuntimeError('Cannot get window extent w/o renderer')
>       928 
>   --> 929         bbox, info, descent = self._get_layout(self._renderer)
>       930         x, y = self.get_unitless_position()
>       931         x, y = self.get_transform().transform_point((x, y))
>
> ~/anaconda3/envs/tf11/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/text.py
>   in _get_layout(self, renderer)
>       311                 w, h, d = renderer.get_text_width_height_descent(clean_line,
>       312                                                         self._fontproperties,
>   --> 313                                                         ismath=ismath)
>       314             else:
>       315                 w, h, d = 0, 0, 0
>
> ~/anaconda3/envs/tf11/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_agg.py
>   in get_text_width_height_descent(self, s, prop, ismath)
>       207             fontsize = prop.get_size_in_points()
>       208             w, h, d = texmanager.get_text_width_height_descent(
>   --> 209                 s, fontsize, renderer=self)
>       210             return w, h, d
>       211
>
> ~/anaconda3/envs/tf11/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/texmanager.py
>   in get_text_width_height_descent(self, tex, fontsize, renderer)
>       462         else:
>       463             # use dviread. It sometimes returns a wrong descent.
>   --> 464             dvifile = self.make_dvi(tex, fontsize)
>       465             with dviread.Dvi(dvifile, 72 * dpi_fraction) as dvi:
>       466                 page = next(iter(dvi))
>
> ~/anaconda3/envs/tf11/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/texmanager.py
>   in make_dvi(self, tex, fontsize)
>       326                 self._run_checked_subprocess(
>       327                     ["latex", "-interaction=nonstopmode", "--halt-on-error",
>   --> 328                      texfile], tex)
>       329             for fname in glob.glob(basefile + '*'):
>       330                 if not fname.endswith(('dvi', 'tex')):
>
> ~/anaconda3/envs/tf11/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/texmanager.py
>   in _run_checked_subprocess(self, command, tex)
>       296             report = subprocess.check_output(command,
>       297                                              cwd=self.texcache,
>   --> 298                                              stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
>       299         except subprocess.CalledProcessError as exc:
>       300             raise RuntimeError(
>
> ~/anaconda3/envs/tf11/lib/python3.6/subprocess.py in
>   check_output(timeout, *popenargs, **kwargs)
>       334 
>       335     return run(*popenargs, stdout=PIPE, timeout=timeout, check=True,
>   --> 336                **kwargs).stdout
>       337 
>       338
>
> ~/anaconda3/envs/tf11/lib/python3.6/subprocess.py in run(input,
>   timeout, check, *popenargs, **kwargs)
>       401         kwargs['stdin'] = PIPE
>       402 
>   --> 403     with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as process:
>       404         try:
>       405             stdout, stderr = process.communicate(input, timeout=timeout)
>
> ~/anaconda3/envs/tf11/lib/python3.6/subprocess.py in **init**(self,
>   args, bufsize, executable, stdin, stdout, stderr, preexec_fn,
>   close_fds, shell, cwd, env, universal_newlines, startupinfo,
>   creationflags, restore_signals, start_new_session, pass_fds, encoding,
>   errors)
>       705                                 c2pread, c2pwrite,
>       706                                 errread, errwrite,
>   --> 707                                 restore_signals, start_new_session)
>       708         except:
>       709             # Cleanup if the child failed starting.
>
> ~/anaconda3/envs/tf11/lib/python3.6/subprocess.py in
>   _execute_child(self, args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds, pass_fds, cwd, env, startupinfo, creationflags, shell, p2cread,
>   p2cwrite, c2pread, c2pwrite, errread, errwrite, restore_signals,
>   start_new_session)    1331                             else:    1332
>   err_msg += ': ' + repr(orig_executable)
>   -> 1333                     raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg)    1334                 raise child_exception_type(err_msg)
>   1335
>
> FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'latex'

Answer (score 3):

The [latex PyPI project](https://pypi.org/project/latex/) which you have installed with pip is *not* a full LaTeX distribution, it instead "allows calling LaTeX from Python without leaving a mess."

The reason your first example works is there is no call to LaTeX. Instead, matplotlib uses its own TeX expression parser, layout engine and fonts: [mathtext](https://matplotlib.org/users/mathtext.html#mathtext-tutorial). In the second example you really are trying to call LaTeX, but you're getting an error since you don't have a LaTeX distribution installed!

You will need to ensure you have a LaTeX distribution installed on your system. Either [TeXLive](https://www.tug.org/texlive/) or [MikTex](https://miktex.org/about) will do the trick. Also, the [matplotlib documentation](https://matplotlib.org/users/usetex.html#usetex-tutorial) on text rendering with LaTeX is very good and I'd recommend you give it a read.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how i changed the path.( Now I am pretty new to coding and I don't understand whats going on at the back. )

opened terminal on my MacBook. typed 'python' and then the following two commands.

```
import os
print(os.environ['PATH'])
```

(you will see a path- lets call it path1)

opened spyder (where i create and run my python files) and in the console again typed

```
import os
print(os.environ['PATH'])
```

(you will again see a path- lets call it path2)

for me these two paths were different. then in my spyder console i typed the following

```
os.environ["PATH"]='path1'
```

i once again checked if both the paths are now matching by typing

```
print(os.environ['PATH'])
```

my latex problem got solved after this.

Comment: Please, Can you improve your answer formatting the code? Is a good practice to improve the answer quality, currently is not very clear.