# Trying to render text on matplotlib plots with LaTex font and getting the error "[Errno 13] Permission denied: 'latex'"

Tags: python, visual-studio, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook, latex

**Problem**

I am trying to follow the [Text rendering with LaTeX matplotlib documentation](https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/text/usetex.html) in order to have the font of my plots (including axis) in Jupyter Notebook be in LaTex. I am hoping to run [this example code](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/text_labels_and_annotations/tex_demo.html) provided in the documentation:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.rcParams['text.usetex'] = True


t = np.linspace(0.0, 1.0, 100)
s = np.cos(4 * np.pi * t) + 2

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(6, 4), tight_layout=True)
ax.plot(t, s)

ax.set_xlabel(r'\textbf{time (s)}')
ax.set_ylabel('\\textit{Velocity (\N{DEGREE SIGN}/sec)}', fontsize=16)
ax.set_title(r'\TeX\ is Number $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^\infty'
             r'\frac{-e^{i\pi}}{2^n}$!', fontsize=16, color='r')
```

[image]

When I try running this in VS code, I get the following error:

> --------------------------------------------------------------------------- PermissionError                           Traceback (most recent call
> last) File
> ~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/IPython/core/formatters.py:339,
> in BaseFormatter.**call**(self, obj)
> 337     pass
> 338 else:
> --> 339     return printer(obj)
> 340 # Finally look for special method names
> 341 method = get_real_method(obj, self.print_method)
>
> File
> ~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/IPython/core/pylabtools.py:151,
> in print_figure(fig, fmt, bbox_inches, base64, **kwargs)
> 148     from matplotlib.backend_bases import FigureCanvasBase
> 149     FigureCanvasBase(fig)
> --> 151 fig.canvas.print_figure(bytes_io, **kw)
> 152 data = bytes_io.getvalue()
> 153 if fmt == 'svg':
>
> File
> ~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/matplotlib-3.5.2-py3.8-linux-x86_64.egg/matplotlib/backend_bases.py:2295,
> in FigureCanvasBase.print_figure(self, filename, dpi, facecolor,
> edgecolor, orientation, format, bbox_inches, pad_inches,
> bbox_extra_artists, backend, **kwargs)    2289     renderer =
> _get_renderer(    2290         self.figure,    2291         functools.partial(    2292             print_method,
> orientation=orientation)    2293     )    2294     with
> getattr(renderer, "_draw_disabled", nullcontext)():
> -> 2295         self.figure.draw(renderer)    2297 if bbox_inches: ...    1703         err_msg = os.strerror(errno_num)
> -> 1704     raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg, err_filename)    1705 raise child_exception_type(err_msg)
>
> PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'latex' <Figure size
> 432x288 with 1 Axes>

**What I have tried**

The first thing I did was make sure I had all of the correct installations the documentation listed, and I chose MikTex as my LaTex installation. It was installed within the AppData folder and the directory where 'latex.exe' can be found is on my system path according to the path in my Environment Variables and appears if I print the path using os.environ within my notebook.

I also tried checking for similar questions on here. The only one I found to be having the same issue is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55430342/how-to-set-latex-path-for-matplotlib) and is unsolved. I also tried following the advice given on that question and it is still giving me the same error. plt.rc command also does not work.

Answer (score 0):

I also had a similar problem before, although not specifically with latex in matplotlib. What I found was that sometimes packages get installed only for the administrator of the PC, and then permissions get denied. I found two solutions:

1. Run your jupyter notebook via Anaconda Prompt by right clicking on the prompt and running as administrator; or
2. Delete everything an reinstall all packages for the whole PC and not only the administrator.

I hope that helps!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).